# Coordinate transforms and reference frames of a mobile robot

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-kinetic, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm developing a vehicle that's fitted with a GPS, IMU and a lidar that will be able to make a map and localise itself in it. To do so various coordinate transforms need to take place, for instance a fixed 'map' frame where the map would be created, a body fixed frame (base_link) for the chassis of the vehicle and then various transforms from the body fixed frame for the IMU/GPS/Lidar to assist in the building of the point cloud map.

My question is, what tf or tf2 tool would I use where?

Are static transforms used for rigid links? For example the IMU/lidar to the base_link (vehicle) etc.

Are the broadcaster/listener combinations used for transforms that vary? For example from the map (world) frame to the base_link.

Thanks for any help, just getting alittle lost with the terminology.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296955/coordinate-transforms-and-reference-frames-of-a-mobile-robot/) by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-11**:
Have you seen the URDF tutorials, especially the [Create your own URDF file](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file) and the ...

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-11**:
[robot_state publisher tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20state%20publisher%20on%20your%20own%20robot)?

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-07-11**:
From what I've read it seemed like the URDF approach was more aligned with manipulator arms and visualizing them etc. Whereas our system should be quite straightforward in that regard

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-07-17**:
I would also suggest looking into URDF and xacro's for the model/TFs of your robot description. I guess you can technically describe your robots TFs with static transforms, but I see no real advantage to this approach in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can use static transforms for rigid links(chassis to sensors, chassis to sensor mounts then sensor mounts to senors etc..) and the broadcaster/listener combinations for the other transforms(like map/odom to base_link, map to odom...). This can be done with tf (I have used only tf for my mobile robot) but you can also use tf2 if you prefer. I have not looked into tf2 much but according to the description it should provide more efficiently the same feature set of tf as well as adding a few new features.
If you are interested more in the changes made between tf and tf2 you can read [this](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration).

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-07-12**:
Thanks for confirming my head was in roughly the right space.
At the moment I've got the gps worling in NED for the world to base_link and it seems to be working really well. Though I'm having trouble using my IMU data to change the orientation of my rigid links (base_link), any pointers?

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-07-12**:
Ideally it would be something like this, where the orientation of the imu is translated through base_link from imu_link (static) altering base_links orientation.

transform.setRotation(q)

br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "world", "imu_link"));

*q is imu quarterion

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-07-12**:
but this doesn't work like it does in my head. Thanks for you help!

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-12**:
Not sure if it will help but you can look into this method **lookupTransform** from [tf](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html) and use to get the right transform between two frames.